# Loopback getting 401 when accessing the current user

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using loopback with the angular sdk on the front-end. I want to get the information about the logged in user; so I do the following:

```
User.getCurrent()
        .$promise
        .then((currentUser) => console.log(currentUser));
```

but the server responds with 401 unauthorized request.

```
code: "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED"
message: "Authorization Required"
name: "Error"
```

How can I get the info of the current user?

Comment: You may want to review: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/426  It may be a result of your ACLs

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an acl for $authenticated users, I think it worked for me in the past. It is not natural, cause one might expect the $owner to be the right choice, but it works.